# Expect script - run code on exit

Tags: expect

Is it possible to run code when an expect script it terminated?

Given the following example;

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

while { true } {
  puts "I am alive"
  sleep 5
}

puts "I am dead"
```

This will continuously print "I am alive". When I press ***<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>*** to kill the script, how can I call a function (or similar) to print "I am dead" on the way out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Handle_a_signal#Tcl) link explains how to handle SIGINT in Expect. This is what you want to do in your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

proc sigint_handler {} {
  puts "I am dead"
  exit
}
trap sigint_handler SIGINT

while { true } {
  puts "I am alive"
  sleep 5
}
```